# Problems with external .lib files and CMake build

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, cpprest-sdk

i installed the cpprestsdk (Casablanca) (cpprest142_2_10) with the conan pkg installer for cmake.
I use a Win 10 System with MS VS Code as IDE. Compiler is MSVC 2019 amd64_x86.
My intellisense for C/C++ found the .h files in my user/conan./ directory.
If I build my Librarys i get non Errors.

But when i try to build the executables I got this:

```
[main] Ordner wird erstellt: Miele_Oculus 
[build] Build wird gestartet.
[proc] Befehl wird ausgeführt: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Projekte/Cpp/dev/Miele_Oculus/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -- /maxcpucount:10
[build] CMake is re-running because C:/Projekte/Cpp/dev/Miele_Oculus/build/app/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is out-of-date.
[build]   the file 'C:/Projekte/Cpp/dev/Miele_Oculus/app/CMakeLists.txt'
[build]   is newer than 'C:/Projekte/Cpp/dev/Miele_Oculus/build/app/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp.depend'
[build]   result='-1'
[build] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
[build] -- Conan: Adjusting output directories
[build] -- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
[build] -- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
[build] -- Conan: Adjusting language standard
[build] -- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: C:/Projekte/Cpp/dev/Miele_Oculus/build
[build] -- Configuring done
[build] -- Generating done
[build] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Projekte/Cpp/dev/Miele_Oculus/build
[build] Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 16.7.0+b89cb5fde für .NET Framework
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
[build] 
[build]   ServerService.vcxproj -> C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\src\ServerService.dir\Debug\ServerService.lib
[build]   Qt_GUI.vcxproj -> C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\src\Qt_GUI.dir\Debug\Qt_GUI.lib
[build]   TANDEM_FABRIKAT.vcxproj -> C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\src\TANDEM_FABRIKAT.dir\Debug\TANDEM_FABRIKAT.lib
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(asyncrt_utils.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(asyncrt_utils.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(uri.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(uri.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(uri_builder.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(uri_builder.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_msg.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_msg.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_client_msg.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_client_msg.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_client.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_client.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(fileio_win32.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(fileio_win32.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(stdafx.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(stdafx.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(json.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(json.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(json_parsing.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(json_parsing.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_compression.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_compression.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_helpers.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_helpers.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(web_utilities.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(web_utilities.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(oauth1.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(oauth1.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_client_winhttp.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_client_winhttp.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(json_serialization.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(json_serialization.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(base64.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": Der Wert "0" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "2" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(base64.obj) : error LNK2038: Konflikt ermittelt für "RuntimeLibrary": Der Wert "MD_DynamicRelease" stimmt nicht mit dem Wert "MDd_DynamicDebug" in main.obj überein. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] LINK : warning LNK4098: Standardbibliothek "MSVCRT" steht in Konflikt mit anderen Bibliotheken; /NODEFAULTLIB:Bibliothek verwenden. [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(web_utilities.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp_CryptProtectMemory" in Funktion ""public: __cdecl web::details::win32_encryption::win32_encryption(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (??0win32_encryption@details@web@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(web_utilities.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__imp_CryptUnprotectMemory" in Funktion ""public: class std::unique_ptr<class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >,class web::details::zero_memory_deleter> __cdecl web::details::win32_encryption::decrypt(void)const " (?decrypt@win32_encryption@details@web@@QEBA?AV?$unique_ptr@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@Vzero_memory_deleter@details@web@@@std@@XZ)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(oauth1.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider" in Funktion ""private: static class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > __cdecl web::http::oauth1::experimental::oauth1_config::_hmac_sha1(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?_hmac_sha1@oauth1_config@experimental@oauth1@http@web@@CA?AV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@7@0@Z)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(oauth1.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "BCryptGetProperty" in Funktion ""private: static class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > __cdecl web::http::oauth1::experimental::oauth1_config::_hmac_sha1(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?_hmac_sha1@oauth1_config@experimental@oauth1@http@web@@CA?AV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@7@0@Z)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(oauth1.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider" in Funktion ""private: static class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > __cdecl web::http::oauth1::experimental::oauth1_config::_hmac_sha1(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?_hmac_sha1@oauth1_config@experimental@oauth1@http@web@@CA?AV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@7@0@Z)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(oauth1.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "BCryptCreateHash" in Funktion ""private: static class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > __cdecl web::http::oauth1::experimental::oauth1_config::_hmac_sha1(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?_hmac_sha1@oauth1_config@experimental@oauth1@http@web@@CA?AV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@7@0@Z)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(oauth1.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "BCryptHashData" in Funktion ""private: static class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > __cdecl web::http::oauth1::experimental::oauth1_config::_hmac_sha1(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?_hmac_sha1@oauth1_config@experimental@oauth1@http@web@@CA?AV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@7@0@Z)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(oauth1.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "BCryptFinishHash" in Funktion ""private: static class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > __cdecl web::http::oauth1::experimental::oauth1_config::_hmac_sha1(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?_hmac_sha1@oauth1_config@experimental@oauth1@http@web@@CA?AV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@7@0@Z)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(oauth1.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "BCryptDestroyHash" in Funktion ""private: static class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > __cdecl web::http::oauth1::experimental::oauth1_config::_hmac_sha1(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?_hmac_sha1@oauth1_config@experimental@oauth1@http@web@@CA?AV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@7@0@Z)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] cpprest142_2_10.lib(http_client_winhttp.obj) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "ERR_reason_error_string" in Funktion ""public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl boost::asio::error::detail::ssl_category::message(int)const " (?message@ssl_category@detail@error@asio@boost@@UEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)". [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\bin\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 35 nicht aufgelöste Externe [C:\Projekte\Cpp\dev\Miele_Oculus\build\app\MIELE_OCULUS_Executable.vcxproj]
[build] Der Build wurde mit dem Exitcode 1 abgeschlossen.
```

Here are my CMakeList.txt file's:

Main List

```
#Minimal benoetigte CMake Version zum ausfuehren dieses CMakeList.txt files
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0)
#Setzte Variable mit dem Projektnamen
set(PROJEKT "MIELE_OCULUS")
#Projekt Var. generieren 
project("${PROJEKT}" VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
#Globale Variablen deklaration

#C++ Standart min. 17
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD          17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS        OFF)

#MAIN Var. generieren (spaeterer Name der ausfuehrbaren Datei)
set(MAIN "${PROJEKT}_Executable")
#Library Variablen generieren
set(LIBRARY_NAME    ServerService)
set(LIBRARY_NAME_2  TANDEM_FABRIKAT)
set(LIBRARY_NAME_3  Qt_GUI)

#Include der eigenen cmake Module
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
include(Documentation)

#Conan packages hinzuefuegen
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

#Librarys hinzufuegen
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/")

#Executables hinzufuegeb
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/app/")
```

Src List:

```
#ServerService#############################################################
add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME} OBJECT

    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/server.cpp"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/connection.cpp"

)
target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC

    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/"
)##########################################################################
#TANDEM_FABRIKAT####################################
add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME_2} OBJECT

    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/fabrikat.cpp"
    
)
target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME_2} PUBLIC

    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/"

)##########################################################################
#Qt_GUI##########################################################
add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME_3} OBJECT

    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mainwindow.cpp"
    
)
target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME_3} PUBLIC

    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/"
    "C:/Qt/5.15.1/msvc2019_64/include"

)##########################################################################
```

app list:

```
#Ausfuehrbare Datei erstellen##############################################
add_executable(${MAIN} 

    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/app/main.cpp"

)##########################################################################
#librarys für ausführbares programm linken#################################
target_link_libraries(
    ${MAIN} PUBLIC
    ${LIBRARY_NAME}
    ${LIBRARY_NAME_2}
    ${LIBRARY_NAME_3}
    cpprest142_2_10
    WS2_32
)##########################################################################
```

If it is of interest I can add conanbuildinfo.cmake but I assume that conon has created it correctly.

Comment: It seems you have a misconfiguration between the time you do the ``conan install`` and the time you build. By default ``conan install`` is installing the Release binaries. If you are building in Debug mode, you want to do ``conan install -s build_type=Debug``. Could this be the case?

Comment: So i tried the build in the debug mode. Now i changed the conan install mode also to debug and i haved to changed the targed_linl_libraries from cpprest142_2_10 to cpprest142_2_10d.
But i got the same Error outputs from cmake :(

Comment: https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan may help ensure that your conan configuration matches your cmake configuration

Comment: The best would be to submit an issue, with clear steps how to reproduce (system, compiler, python version, cmake version, compiler version) to https://github.com/conan-io/conan